# Mysql select query to omit specific fileds

Tags: mysql

we can create mysql query to select all fields, we can create mysql query to select necessary fields.

select * to select all fields

select fieldname to select specific fields, **but is there any way to select all fields except 1 or 2**

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this provided you have permissions to execute this query:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', 
     (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), '<colums that you dont want>,', '') 
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
      WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<yourtablename>' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '<yourdatabasename>'), 
     ' FROM <yourtablename>');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

And if you dont have the permission to execute the above query then you have to list all the columns explicitly which you want to show and which you dont.

Answer (score 2):

In case of select specific fields you have no way but to select the specific columns as

```
select col1, col2, col3 ... from table_name
```

Leave the columns which you do not want to select and add those you want to select.

Answer (score 2):

This should help

```
SET @query =  CONCAT('SELECT ', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), '<OMITTED COLUMN>,', '') FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<TABLE NAME>' ), ' FROM     <TABLE NAME>');

prepare statement from  @query;
execute statement
```